# Parsing Json file with jackson : property names contains "_" character

Tags: android, json

I have a json file with property names contains "_" character, and i'm wondering if it can be parsed nicely with jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from jackson API: `"_user" is translated to user` when setting `PropertyNamingStrategy` to `PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy`
`http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.html

if you need help in using `PropertyNamingStartegy` then have a look at http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/how-to-use-propertynamingstrategy-in-jackson.html

Comment: thank you so much for these links, it's really clear.